# Difference between R.string.xxx and getString(R.string.xxx)?

Tags: android, android-resources, getstring

What is the difference between two ways to obtain a string from resources:

```
setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string);
```

OR

```
setPositiveButton((getString(R.string.some_string));
```

?

In both cases I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R.string.some_string
```

is a public final static int that is a fixed ID to a specific String in your R.java file. This is generated automatically.

```
getString(R.string.some_string)
```

returns the String referenced by the above by reading the R.java file.

It depends on the implementation of

```
setPositiveButton(String)
```

and

```
setPositiveButton(int)
```

what difference internally is made, like with error checks.

Answer (score 2):

setPositiveButton has multiple overloads that accept different types of arguments.

When calling

```
setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string);
```

You are telling your application to set the positive buttons text equal to the string that is referenced by your resource ID "some_string".

Where as

```
setPositiveButton((getString(R.string.some_string));
```

You are fetching the String value for "some_string" and then assigning that to your positive button;

They work out to be the same because the 1st method does the "getString(R.string.some_string)" portion for you

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is that, with **getString** you can format your String and translate it. For example, in your **strings.xml** file you can have:

```
<string name="message">Hello, %1$s</string>
```

And in some some translation XML file you can have the same, but in another language:

```
<string name="message">Hola, %1$s</string>
```

But the good thing is that when you want to show a message and get it translated, you only have to do this:

```
String message = getString(R.string.message, "John Doe");
```

And, in the english version it will be *Hello, John Doe*. But in the spanish version it will be *Hola, John Doe*.

Not only will translate it, but format it and will give you more control over your code.